# C# console application - constant zero value in variable

Tags: c#, return

I almost got my little console-app working, the only problem is that the variable `totalComm` keeps having the value 0.

I tried everything, I probably just overlooked a small fix which would solve the problem.

Thanks in advance

Philip

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace CommissionCalculator
{
 class Program
  {
    public static void Main()
    {
        double total;
        double comm = 0;
        double totalComm = 0;
        string name = "";

        string inputLetter = "";
        int whilecount = 0;           

        while (inputLetter != "z")
        {
            if (whilecount == 0)
            {
                Title();
                whilecount = whilecount + 1;
            }

            getNameSales(out inputLetter, out name, out total, comm, totalComm);

            calcComm(total, out comm);

            outputVar(name, total, comm);

            totalCommCalc(comm, totalComm);
        }
    }

    public static void Title()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\n           Sunshine Hot Tubs \n        Sales Commissions Report\n");
    }

    public static void getNameSales(out string inputLetter, out string name, out double total, double comm, double totalComm)
    {
        name = "";
        inputLetter = "";
        total = 0;

        Console.WriteLine("\nEnter salespersons initial a,b or e or enter z to quit");

        inputLetter = Console.ReadLine();

            if (inputLetter == "a")
            {
                name = "Andrea";

                string inValue;
                double sale = 0;
                total = 0;

                for (int count = 1; count <= 3; ++count)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Please enter sale: ");
                    inValue = Console.ReadLine();
                    sale = Convert.ToDouble(inValue);

                    total = total + sale;
                }
            }
            else if (inputLetter == "b")
            {
                name = "Brittany";

                string inValue;
                double sale = 0;
                total = 0;

                for (int count = 1; count <= 3; ++count)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Please enter sale: ");
                    inValue = Console.ReadLine();
                    sale = Convert.ToDouble(inValue);

                    total = total + sale;
                }
            }
            else if (inputLetter == "e")
            {
                name = "Eric";

                string inValue;
                double sale = 0;
                total = 0;

                for (int count = 1; count <= 3; ++count)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Please enter sale: ");
                    inValue = Console.ReadLine();
                    sale = Convert.ToDouble(inValue);

                    total = total + sale;
                }
            }
            else if (inputLetter == "z")
            {
                totalCommCalc(comm, totalComm);

                Console.WriteLine("Total commssion paid: {0:C}", totalComm);

                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }

    public static void calcComm(double total, out double comm)
    {
        comm = total * 0.2;
    }

    public static double totalCommCalc(double comm, double totalComm)
    {            
        totalComm = totalComm + comm;

        return totalComm;
    }

    public static void outputVar(string name, double total, double comm)        
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("\n Name\t       Total sales\t     Commission \n{0}     \t    {1}     \t      {2}", name, total, comm);            
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

totalComm is passed by *value* to totalCommCalc.  Either pass it by *reference*, or return it from totalCommCalc and assign back to totalComm.

When a variable is passed by value, a *copy* is placed on the stack of the method you call.  Changes to that copy do not affect the original.

When you pass by *reference*, the address of the original is placed on the stack, and changes *do* affect the original.

Option 1:

```
// Passed by reference.
// Changes affect original.  
// Has side effects.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_%28computer_science%29
totalCommCalc(comm, ref totalComm);
```

Option 2:

```
// Preferred.  Passed by value.  
// Result is assigned to a variable.  
// No side effects.
totalComm = totalCommCalc(comm, totalComm);
```

I would prefer the second form, as code that has [side effects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_%28computer_science%29) can be harder to understand and maintain as it grows.

Comment: I accepted your answer, because you explained it to me the best. I'm really new with c#, thanks a lot you saved me from a big headache :D

Answer (score 0):

The call to "totalCommCalc"  should either store the return value or use the out keyword, like the other methods. For consistency with your other methods I would use the out and remove the return value.

```
 totalCommCalc(comm, out totalComm);
```

OR

```
totalComm = totalCommCalc(comm, totalComm)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing in `totalComm` by *value*, not by *reference*.  If you want the change to `totalComm` to persist, either make it a `ref` parameter or, if appropriate, *return* the value from the functions.

To pass by reference:

```
....
getNameSales(out inputLetter, out name, out total, comm, ref totalComm);
....

public static void getNameSales(out string inputLetter, out string name, out double total, double comm, ref double totalComm)
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont use `ref` (According to @Eric J: code with [side effects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_%28computer_science%29) can be harder to understand and maintain as it grows)

Just change one line i.e. assign your variable with function returned value.

```
totalComm = totalCommCalc(comm, totalComm);
```

That's it.